# Running Laravel queues automatically

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, queue

I have implemented **Laravel** queue.The thing is i have to run the command `php artisan queue:listen` every time.Is there any way that the jobs get executed automatically without running any command.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Then you can follow the the detailed instructions from the Laravel Documentation on how to install and use [Supervisor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#supervisor-configuration) to manage the queue listener.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a one-liner to put into your crontab (let it run, let say, every 5 minutes):

```
cd /path/to/your/project && jobs -l | grep `cat queue.pid` || { nohup /usr/bin/php artisan queue:listen & echo $! > queue.pid; }
```

two variables here:
1. `/path/to/your/project` -- is your Laravel project root. Effectively, the folder, where `php artisan` would work;
2. `/usr/bin/php` -- path to PHP executable on the server (`which php`)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you use Linux you can use for example [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) which will run `php artisan queue:listen` (you need to add this command to supervisor configuration file) and it will make sure all the time this command is running.